# How to set the max running jobs number in lsf

Tags: lsf

I use IBM lsf. I want to configure the max running jobs number.

for example, per-user can submit 100000 jobs, but only 10 job can be runned, the other jobs are pending.

I have tried to set  UJOB_LIMIT in lsb.queues

```
 UJOB_LIMIT:Specifies the per-user job slot limit for the queue
```

and MAX_JOBS in lsb.users

```
MAX_JOBS: Per-user or per-group job slot limit for the cluster. Total number of job slots that
```

each user or user group can use in the cluster.

and MAX_PEND_JOBS in lsb.users

```
MAX_PEND_JOBS: Per-user or per-group pending job limit.
```

But they are wrong. I don't know how to set , who can give me a help?

Answer (score 1):

To allow a user to submit 100000 jobs but only run 10 of them at a time, set this in lsb.users:

```
Begin User
USER_NAME         MAX_JOBS    MAX_PEND_JOBS
myuser                  10            99990
End User
```

(99990 = 100000 - 10).

These limits will apply to the whole cluster